# LwIP into NUC970_NonOS_BSP-master incorrect works LWIP_DEBUG option

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, lwip, nuvoton

I'm trying build LwIP 1.4.1 (this version uses vendor for example) and I want to build with diagnostic messages for UDP.
Problem: In debug.h condition `#ifdef LWIP_DEBUG` builds as undefined, but if `#define LWIP_DEBUG exist` warning about redefine it.

Updated: it repeatable in four files.

udp.c

```
#include "lwip/opt.h"

err_t
udp_bind(struct udp_pcb *pcb, ip_addr_t *ipaddr, u16_t port)
{
    // My comment
  LWIP_DEBUGF(UDP_DEBUG | LWIP_DBG_TRACE, ("udp_bind(ipaddr = "));
  return ERR_OK;
}
```

opt.h

```
#ifndef __LWIP_OPT_H__
#define __LWIP_OPT_H__

#include "lwipopts.h"
#include "lwip/debug.h"

#endif /* __LWIP_OPT_H__ */
```

lwipopts.h

```
#ifndef __LWIPOPTS_H__
#define __LWIPOPTS_H__

#include "lwipopts.h"
#include "lwip/debug.h"

#define LWIP_DEBUG  1
#define UDP_DEBUG   LWIP_DBG_ON


#endif /* __LWIPOPTS_H__ */
```

and debug.h

```
#ifndef __LWIP_DEBUG_H__
#define __LWIP_DEBUG_H__

#include "lwip/opt.h"

//#define LWIP_DEBUG  exist
#ifdef LWIP_DEBUG
#define LWIP_DEBUGF(debug, message) do { if ((debug) & 0x80U)  { \
                                 LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG(message); \
                               } } while(0)

#else  /* LWIP_DEBUG */
#define LWIP_DEBUGF(debug, message) 
#endif /* LWIP_DEBUG */

#endif /* __LWIP_DEBUG_H__ */
```

Comment: For control I uses 
```gcc -E -Iincludepath udp.c > udp.e
``` 
and see generated text, for example - udp_bind()

Comment: How many translation units do you compile? In which of them has `LWIP_DEBUGF` no body, and which of them triggers the warnings? To reproduce, [edit] your question please, consider a [mre] and/or add a link to the original sources.

Comment: So the preprocessor is warning you that you redefine an existing macro.  Other than that I don't see the problem.  Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: @G.M. , Macro defined, but condition #ifdef this one works like undefined, When it defines manually - comiler warning about macro defined.  I'm trying minimise as recommended the busybee

Comment: @G.M. ,  I updated question. Can you check it, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you try on purpose to define it in multiple headers, that may be included at the same time from a .c file, each header needs to do something like:

```c
#ifndef LWIP_DEBUG
  #define LWIP_DEBUG 1
#endif
```

Or alternatively:

```c
#undef LWIP_DEBUG
#define LWIP_DEBUG 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found problem: remove any includes from `lwipopts.h`.

It reproduces in two files, **udp.c** and modifed **lwipopts.h**

```
#ifndef __LWIPOPTS_H__
#define __LWIPOPTS_H__

#include "lwipopts.h"
//#include "lwip/debug.h" 
/* REDUCED BODY BEGIN */
//#define LWIP_DEBUG  exist
#ifdef LWIP_DEBUG
#define LWIP_DEBUGF(debug, message) do { printf("%d, %s\n", debug, message); } while(0)
#else  /* LWIP_DEBUG */
#define LWIP_DEBUGF(debug, message) 
#endif /* LWIP_DEBUG */
/* REDUCED BODY END */

#define LWIP_DEBUG  1
#define UDP_DEBUG   LWIP_DBG_ON

#endif /* __LWIPOPTS_H__ */
```

Definition `LWIP_DEBUG` after `#ifdef LWIP_DEBUG` condition.
It is because users **lwipopts.h** contain

```
#include "lwipopts.h"
#include "lwip/debug.h"
```

**lwipopts.h** should not contain any include directive!
Little bit explain:
How it should be

```
#include "lwip/opt.h"
  #include "lwipopts.h"
  // BODY lwipopts.h
  #include "lwip/debug.h"
    //#include "opt.h" /* guarded */
  // BODY debug.h
```

How it is in git Nuvoton (reduced):

```
#include "lwip/opt.h" /* udp.c */
  #include "lwipopts.h"
    //#include "lwipopts.h"  /* guarded */
    #include "lwip/debug.h"
      //#include "lwip/opt.h"  /* guarded */
      // BODY debug.h
    // BODY lwipopts.h
  //#include "lwip/debug.h" /* guarded */
    //#include "lwip/opt.h" /* guarded */
```

So, bodies of **debug.h** and **lwipopts.h** swaped.